# Select an element if ID partially matches

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-1"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lien 1</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-2"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lien 2</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Lien 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<article id="content">
  <div id="post-1" class="page">
    <p>content post 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="post-2" class="page">
    <p>content post 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="post-3" class="page">
    <p>content post 3</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

The idea is the following: if the number after **menu-item-** matches the number after **post-** then do something.

How do I do that?

The final goal is to display each div when i click on the corresponding menu link

```
menu-item-1 -> display post-1
menu-item-2 -> display post-2
menu-item-3 -> display post-3
```

Thanks !

Comment: I'd suggest using `href="#post-1"`, etc on the links.

Comment: @Tonani if any answers helped, you might want to consider marking one as accepted :)

Comment: done! sorry, i was very busy at work :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('nav').on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    $('#post-' + this.id.replace('menu-item-', '')).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fKgdL/1

Answer (score 2):

```
$('nav li').click(function() {
   // Optional: hide other posts 
   $('.page').hide();

   // Show the correct post
   var id = this.id.replace('menu-item-', '');
   $('#post-' + id).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $id = $(this).closest('li').prop('id'); // Get the id
    $("#post-"+id.split("-")[2]).show();     // show the post
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('nav li').click(function() {
   var id = this.value.split('-')[1];
   var ele = $('#post-' + id);
   ele.show();
   $('.page').not(ele).hide();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click(function(){

  var pID= $(this).attr('id').split('-')[2];
  $('#content').find('div').each(function(){

    if(pID==$(this).attr('id').split('-')[1]){

      //DO SOMETHING HERE...
    }
  });
});
```